# Excel on Mac doesn't show Chinese characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, office-for-mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to import (and view correctly) Chinese UTF-8 encoded CSV file with Excel 2011 on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/347852/how-to-import-and-view-correctly-chinese-utf-8encoded-csv-file-with-excel-201)

I downloaded an Excel file, which is supposed to contain Chinese characters. Excel on my Mac with OS X Snow Leopard is not able to show Chinese characters.

I wonder if in Excel, there is a way you tell the application which encoding to use when viewing the content. Would I need to select unicode or something else there?

Any clarification on these concepts would be highly useful.

Comment: What characters you saw?  Maybe you can capture the screens and post here.  Or, maybe you change the font (e.g., SimHei)?

Comment: yes, so it boils down to how to change font encoding (being used to view content) in mac/excel